# How can I fetch a "particular minor version" of an artifact in Maven

Tags: maven

Is there a way to specify minor version along with the major one? For example for spring release "4.0.0", there are two minor versions

```
spring-aop-4.0.0.BUILD-20130814.154539-196.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.BUILD-20130823.020236-203
```

Can I specify a specific minor version along with the dependency?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are what Maven would consider SNAPSHOT builds, which usually are intermediate versions in between proper releases. If you specify your version as `4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` Maven retrieves the most recent one.

Note that in general these should be consider development versions, not necessarily fit for general use.

Comment: Ya agree, that these are not for general purpose use, am just playing with there websockets support to be released with version 4.0. This means I can use the build number as 4.0.0.BUILD-20130814.154539-196 to fetch a specific minor release instead of 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT which will always fetch latest one! Let me try it out.